# Notify all Users using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

In my application. I am writing blogs.
 On submitting a blog, a request is sent to Website Admin for approval.

So i want these request be loaded on Admin's page without reloading.

Now For my ADMIN,

```
    $(':button').click(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url:'admin_approval.php',
        data: {'id': id},
        success: function(data)
        {
            $(':button[id='+id+'], p[id='+id+'], p[id=date'+id+'], pre[id='+id+']').hide();

        }
    });

});
```

On approval, a flag in the database is Set from 0 to 1

Owing to this action I want my show_blog.php to get refreshed for all Users

In my show_blog.php, I'm retrieving all blogs from my database..

Any solution to the problem, Can i have repeated Ajax calls every 1 minute ??

Comment: On the page which displays the blogs, have an AJAX call which retrieves the latest blog post.

Comment: Please show us your effort till now, what error are you getting etc. Per the rule, we cannot write code for you.

Comment: Give example of implementation... I know where i have to use Ajax, but how is something I don't know !

Comment: @Vaido please edit your question to clarify the problem. Give either more precise verbal description or use pseudocode, or flowchart, code pieces.